# ReactJS How to call a function to change JSON dict value after setState?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Let us say I currently have a ReactJS file where the code is like so:

```
class myFunction extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/data').then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
            this.setState({data: JSON_data})
    }

    render() {
        return(
                <h1>Name: {data.name}</h1>
                <p>Birthday:{data.birthday} </p>
        )
    }
}

export default myFunction;
```

Inside my data variable, it will be a library with two key/values (1 for name and 1 for birthday). So an example might be:

```
data = {
    "name": "Julia"
    "birthday": "9/3",
}
```

The website when I run will correctly show something like:

```
Name: Julia
Birthday: 9/3
```

However, I want to add a function that changes the birthday string from '9/3' to something like 'March 9th'. I have the function, we will call birthdayFormatter(), already implemented, but how would I call the function in a way where in setState, it would change the '9/3' to 'March 9th' so in the render return, I should see:

```
Name: Julia
Birthday: March 9th
```

I have been trying to call functions insider the render() return but none of these have worked. How would I do something like this? Just note that this should be done with no button clicks whatsoever, just normally loading the page.

Comment: So you're saying you need the update to take place before it is stored in state, and not when it is rendered?

Comment: Because unless there is some strange requirement not to do so, the easier way would be to call it in the render like this: `<p>Birthday:{birthdayFormatter(data.birthday)} </p>`

Comment: I am kinda new to ReactJS but I just want it so when it is rendered, the birthday shows the "March 9th" not "9/3". I'm guessing that means I need it to change in setState.

Comment: Not necessarily. I think the example above should work in your case if the `birthdayFormatter` function is already working correctly.

Comment: My answer updates the state with the formatted date, but actually Brian's idea could help as well or even be a better solution as long you want to use the formatted value only on this render. If you want to use the formatted data in other places to, it is better to save it in the state formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new object `data` with the new value for `birthday` after calling `birthdayFormatter()`, only then, store it in the state using `setState()`. Like so:

```
let currState = {...this.state};
currState.data.birthday = birthdayFormatter(currState.data.birthday);
this.setState(currState);
```

However, you said you want it done on loadup, so just call it after fetching and before setting the state:

```
class myFunction extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/data').then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
            data.birthday = birthdayFormatter(data.birthday); //here
            this.setState({data: JSON_data}); 
    }

    render() {
        return(
                <h1>Name: {this.state.data.name}</h1>
                <p>Birthday:{this.state.data.birthday} </p>
        )
    }
}

export default myFunction;
```

Comment: Where exactly should the function birthdayFormatter be in this case? I've put it above componentDidMount() and below it and it keeps telling me the function is not defined.

Comment: I think you will need to bind something.. but try calling it `this.birthdayFormatter` for a sec...